# PHP HTTP request to get JSON response

Tags: php, json, http

I am a novice in PHP. I have a URL and I need generate a GET request to this URL and get a JSON response. How might I achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean asynchronously? E.g. with ajax?

Comment: No, request must be synchronously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform GET requests using the following. . . provided PHP is not in safe mode.

[`file_get_contents();`](http://php.net/file_get_contents)

[`curl();`](http://php.net/curl)

Comment: "curl" is not a function. (and the semicolon isn't part of the function regardless)

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://php.net/curl library to send GET requests.